# Prove that every ideal in $\Bbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, ideals

I have a question about the following proof for the theorem:

> Prove that every ideal in $\Bbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal.

[image]

In Case 2, I do not understand how the principle of well-ordering is used. How it is known that $I$ is a subset of $\Bbb{N}$?

Comment: $I$ is not a subset of $N,$ but the set of positive elements of $I$ is.

Comment: Adding to saulspatz's comment, if $n\in I$, then $-n\in I$, hence if $I\ne\{0\}$, then $I$ contains positive elements.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the set $\lbrace z \in I\;|\; z \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace \neq \emptyset$. For this, take $0, a \in I$ so
$$0 - a\;\mathrm{and}\;0+a \in I$$
Thus, $a, -a \in I$. Therefore, theres exists a subset of natural numbers contained in $I$.

Comment: So the principle of well-ordering can be used on $I$ even if $I$ only contains a subset of $\Bbb{N}$ and $I$ is not in fact a subset of $\Bbb{N}$? Or it is saying that the smallest positive element in $I$ will have a negative form and so only the positive elements are considered and hence there is a subset of $\Bbb{N}$?

Comment: @numericalorange The set you're applying the well-ordering property to is not $I$, but $I \cap \mathbb{N}^+$ which is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ (and a nonempty subset by the argument given in the answer).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Then it cannot be concluded that $I$ has a smallest element?

Comment: @numericalorange No, in fact the only ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ with a smallest element is $\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I see... that is why I do not understand why they use such a principle to begin with when it doesn't make sense to me...